# Classes in subfolders in app/models don't get loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to have a folder of related Models in my Rails 4 app. Why don't classes in app/models/debt_models get loaded?

I guess there is a work around by how come Rails just doesn't recursively go through folders under app/models? Is there a reason? Seems like this is something Rails should do without me having to tell Rails to do that.

Comment: How are you trying to access them? Are they properly namespaced?

Comment: models in app/models are available to the app. models in app/models/debt_models are not available.

Comment: Right, I understand that. I believe you're not namespacing them properly.

Comment: I just feel like everything under /models should be loaded by rails

Comment: It is. I believe you're not namespacing them properly. It's there a reason you won't address my comments and the answer?

Answer (score 3):

You just have to follow conventions. If you put models in `debt_models`, it means you namespace them like:

```
module DebtModels
  class Foo
```

Path: `app/models/debt_models/foo.rb`